# PHP Page That Prevents Submission based on time/date

Tags: javascript, php

I have a page for my students to login for attendance, really simple, just a name and student id box and it clocks them for the day with a time recording and all that. However, I am trying to implement a 'lock out' system so that they cannot mark attendance outside of class time. The days are Tuesday and Thursday from 11-1215. I can get the time lockout to work or not work if the time is right, but they days are not working, and I don't really know why. Any help would be appreciated.

```
if (date('G')<=11 || date('G')>= 12 && date('N') !=3 || date('N') !=5)
{
header ('Location: /noattend.php');
exit();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend brushing up on how [Operator Precedence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) is performed in PHP. In this specific scenario, your conditions will be evaluated from left-to-right, which probably isn't what you intended.

Instead, group your conditions appropriately to meet your logical criteria (and change the logical `OR` for the day of the week to a logical `AND`, thanks @enhzflep):

```
if ((date('G')<=11 || date('G')>= 12) && (date('N') !=2 && date('N') !=4))
{
    header ('Location: /noattend.php');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Isn't the problem not with precedence, but instead with the logic? I.e ( (date != 3) || (date != 5) ) is _always_ going to evaluate to true. If the date is 3, then it isn't 5, similar for the reverse. If that or operator was changed for the and one, it'd work, wouldn't it!?

Comment: That did it; I haven't run into the Operator Precedence stuff before, but am looking at it now, thank you

Comment: @enhzflep Thanks, I moved a bit too fast on this one to realize that was an issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

`N` gives you an [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) numeric representation of the day of the week meaning that the first day of the week is Monday. So Tuesday is 2 and Thursday is 4.

And as @esqew mentioned you have a problem with logic operators as well.